# Onclick, copy image url wrapped in [img] tags to clipboard

Tags: copy, clipboard, bbcode, imageurl

Since yesterday night I've been searching the Internet for the correct answer to my question. So far, nothing has worked out.

I offer a free eCard-Service on my private website. The textarea is [bbCode](https://www.bbcode.org) based with smileys etc., and it all works perfect with `onclick`. But now, I have a lot more smileys in an extra window through a 'show more smileys' link.

What I like to do is, when the user clicks on a smiley, the bbCode to embed it should be copied to the clipboard. It should look like this:

```
[img]full image address[/img]
```

So that my visitors only have to paste the code into the textarea with Ctrl+V.

Comment: There is no need to tell the story, just tell your problem with details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)